# Adding an inline image to a title using css

Tags: html, css

I have some titles layouts in my css file, like h1 and h2. Sometimes I need a simple title like: `<h1>Most readed</h1>` and some times I need to add an image to the begining of the title like: [image]. How can I do this using a class, like `<h1 class="with_image_1">`?

Comment: "Most Readed" should probably say "Most Read"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way of doing this would be to set the image as the `background-image` and add padding to move the text out of the way, so assuming your image is 50 px wide:

```
.with_image_1 {
background: url("/path/to/image.png") left no-repeat transparent;
padding-left: 50px;
}
```

You can then mess with the padding and the image placement to get everything lined up nicely

Answer (score 0):

you just use a background image in your css:

```
.with_image_1 {background-image: url(some/image/path.png); 
               width:100px; height:100px;}
```

you may want to move the text too else it will display on top of your shiny image... to do this put the text in the h1 tag in a span, then shift the span off the screen:

```
<h1 class="with_image_1"><span>Title</span></h1>

.with_image_1 span {position:relative; left:-2000px;}
```

Comment: I think he meant adding an image to the side of the text, not replacing the heading altogether